# Matplotlib: Multiple vertically aligned anchored texts

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

I am using anchored text for a matplotlib dynamic plot:

```
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid.anchored_artists import AnchoredText
...
at = AnchoredText('flag: ' + var,
                      prop=dict(size=8), frameon=True,
                      loc=1,
)
at.patch.set_boxstyle('round,pad=0.,rounding_size=0.2')
ax.add_artist(at)
```

How can I add multiple Anchored texts aligned vertically?

Somethig like this:

[image]

And eventually:

[image]